# Login with Facebook while writing to a MySQL database in AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For the past week I have been trying to use the login with Facebook API as well as learn a bit more about MySQL. With the help of a few sources I have successfully done that. However I am having to now combine those two projects into one project using AJAX (as I don't want to launch separate pages, but rather to stay in the same page.

Here is my code for the MySQL, as it stand right now it is perfect with the exception that it goes to script.php to run (I need to convert this to AJAX, I believe):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="script.php" method="post">
<p>first name:
  <input name="namefirst" type="text" id="namefirst" maxlength="35">
</p>
<p>last name:
  <input name="namelast" type="text" id="namelast" maxlength="50">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="textarea">review:</label>
  <textarea name="text" maxlength="65535" id="text"></textarea>
</p>
<p><input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the script.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$firstname = filter_var(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["namefirst"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lastname = filter_var(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["namelast"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$text = filter_var(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["text"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$sql = "INSERT INTO tabel (firstname, lastname, text)
VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$text')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    echo "<br><br><br>" . $namefirst . "<br><br>" . $namelast . "<br><br>" . $review;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Now I am trying to combine this project with this project, which uses Facebook's API to get log in and make a MySQL entry.

Here is the code for that (fbindex.php):

```
<?php
// Include FB config file && User class
require_once 'fbConfig.php';
require_once 'User.class.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

          // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // Getting user facebook profile info
    try {
        $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture');
        $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // Redirect user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // Initialize User class
    $user = new User();

    // Insert or update user data to the database
    $fbUserData = array(
        'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
        'oauth_uid'     => $fbUserProfile['id'],
        'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
        'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
        'picture'       => $fbUserProfile['picture']['url'],
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);

    // Put user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

    // Get logout url
    $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, $redirectURL.'logout.php');

    // Render facebook profile data
    if(!empty($userData)){
        $output  = '<h2 style="color:#999999;">Facebook Profile Details</h2>';
        $output .= '<div style="position: relative;">';
        $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['cover'].'" />';
        $output .= '<img style="position: absolute; top: 90%; left: 25%;" src="'.$userData['picture'].'"/>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : '.$userData['oauth_uid'];
        $output .= '<br/>Name : '.$userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
        $output .= '<br/>Email : '.$userData['email'];
    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }

}else{
    // Get login url
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

    // Render facebook login button
    $output = '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'">click here to login with facebook</a>';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display login button / Facebook profile information -->
    <div><?php echo $output; ?></div>
</body>
```

The attached two documents just handle the facebook login API info and the SQL databasing. My question is how do I combine these two, so after successful Facebook login process $post from index.php while not leaving the page?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll try to guide you into a path to a solution (for the moment I will ignore the ajax thing, because it maybe just make it more complicated :-) )

Your `fbindex.php` does following:

1. checks if user is logged in with facebook - already okay
2. when not print link to fb (or possible redirect to fb) - already okay
3. when logged in print fb-userdata

You need now the improve step 3 - In this case it looks like you need additional info from the user - so just move your `form` to step 3 and get rid of firstname/lastname (provided by fb already).

When the user submit your form (basically fills the `text` field) the actions points to `script.php`.
At the beginning of `script.php` don't forget on `session_start()` then you are able to access the fb-userdata again.

In `script.php` modify how the data is obtained

```
$firstname = $_SESSION['userData']['first_name'];
$lastname = $_SESSION['userData']['last_name'];
$text = filter_var(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["text"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

and save it to db (you already do that)

I would recommend you to also save the `oauth_uid` - so you can identify if you already have inserted the user in your table when he is logging in with fb again next time

If this is working you can also rewrite it with ajax - in this case your `form` has no action to `script.php` instead you are sending the data with JavaScript to `script.php` - so you will stay on the same page.
(j4i - in my code example I used also `jQuery`)

```
//include jquery

<form id="registerForm">
  <p>
    <label for="textarea">review:</label>
    <textarea name="text" maxlength="65535" id="text"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var text = $("#text").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: "text=" + text,
        success: function(){
          //is called when script.php is finished - do whatever you want now
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```